# Lock in multithreading with a loop in it accessing to the same piece of data

Tags: c, multithreading

So I have a 5 threads adding a same counter at the same time. The thread function is something like:

```
define MAX_NUM 1000;
int counter;
int isMax;

thread_function(){
  while (isMax == 0) {
    if (counter < MAX_NUM) {
      counter++
    } else {
      isMax = 1;
    }
  }
}
```

and I'm trying to add lock to the thread so only one thread changes the data at a time.

```
define MAX_NUM 1000;
int counter;
int isMax;
Lock *myLock;

thread_function(){
  while (isMax == 0) {
    lock_acquire(myLock);
    if (counter < MAX_NUM) {
      counter++;
    } else {
      isMax = 1;
    }
    lock_release(myLock);
  }
}
```

For some reason this doesn't stop different threads from adding the counter at the same time. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work and how to fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing the return value from `lock_acquire` might tell you what's wrong.

Comment: You're also accessing `isMax` from multiple threads without any locking.

Comment: Perhaps your `lock_acquire` and `lock_release` functions does not work ? You should post your complete code.

Answer (score 0):

After lock_release(myLock) you must relinquish the CPU. If you use posix threads you can use sched_yield(). In addition, some compilers can optimize isMax, so define it as "volatile int" instead of "int"

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this via a thing called atomic fetch and add, without requiring locks.

```
__atomic_fetch_add(&counter, 1, __ATOMIC_SEQ_CST);
```

This will increment the counter regardless of the other threads behavior; there's a catch however - if you want to stop at exactly MAX_NUM then this method is faulty since it could exceed this value.
However, you can resort to another method called compare-and-swap to verify that the counter has the same value and to the CAS instruction:

```
int oldCounter = counter;
//..check here that the value < MAX_NUM
__sync_bool_compare_and_swap(&counter, oldCounter, oldCounter+1);
```

References on atomic operations [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.1/gcc/Atomic-Builtins.html).